# Single PHP Function To Replace Text With Emoticons Or Filter Words

Tags: php, foreach, filter, str-replace, emoticons

So I'm trying to find a way to build a function that will replace text with an image if it's an emoticon or with a filtered word if it is a prohibited word.

I've taken a look at this code:

```
$smiles = array(
  'xD'  => 'devil.png',
  '>:)' => 'devil.png',
  'x('  => 'angry.png',
  ':((' => 'cry.png',
  ':*'  => 'kiss.png',
  ':))' => 'laugh.png',
  ':D'  => 'laugh.png',
  ':-D' => 'laugh.png',
  ':x'  => 'love.png',
  '(:|' => 'sleepy.png',
  ':)'  => 'smile.png',
  ':-)' => 'smile.png',
  ':('  => 'sad.png',
  ':-(' => 'sad.png',
  ';)'  => 'wink.png',
  ';-)' => 'wink.png'
);

foreach($smiles as $key => $img) {
    $msg = str_replace($key, '<img src="emotions/'.$img.'" height="18" width="18" />', $msg);
}
echo $msg;
```

That seems simple enough, but what if I want to add something like `'BadWord1' => '********'`

I know how to add it to this script since I would just add that new line, but it would try to turn it into an image.

Is it possible to write a function that would replace both text and images?

On a long stretch I'm also wanting to remove textarea line breaks and replace them with `<br>` instead using something like `$val = str_replace( array("\n","\r","\r\n"), '<br />', $val );`

But I can't seem to think of a way to accomplish all three within one function.

My main goal is when a textarea is submitted to call the text to the function like `replaceText($textareaText)` and anything within the text that needs replaced gets replaced.

Will I need separate functions?

I am going to keep working on this on my own so if I come up with any possible developments I will update my question to include it.

EDIT: Here is what I have come up with. Would you consider this sufficient?

```
function replaceText($msg) {
$replaceableText = array(
  'xD'  => '<img src="emoticons/devil.png" height="18" width="18">',
  '>:)' => '<img src="emoticons/devil.png" height="18" width="18">',
  'x('  => '<img src="emoticons/angry.png" height="18" width="18">',
  ':((' => '<img src="emoticons/cry.png" height="18" width="18">',
  ':*'  => '<img src="emoticons/kiss.png" height="18" width="18">',
  ':))' => '<img src="emoticons/laugh.png" height="18" width="18">',
  ':D'  => '<img src="emoticons/laugh.png" height="18" width="18">',
  ':-D' => '<img src="emoticons/laugh.png" height="18" width="18">',
  ':x'  => '<img src="emoticons/love.png" height="18" width="18">',
  '(:|' => '<img src="emoticons/sleepy.png" height="18" width="18">',
  ':)'  => '<img src="emoticons/smile.png" height="18" width="18">',
  ':-)' => '<img src="emoticons/smile.png" height="18" width="18">',
  ':('  => '<img src="emoticons/sad.png" height="18" width="18">',
  ':-(' => '<img src="emoticons/sad.png" height="18" width="18">',
  ';)'  => '<img src="emoticons/wink.png" height="18" width="18">',
  ';-)' => '<img src="emoticons/wink.png" height="18" width="18">',
  '\n' => '<br>',
  '\r' => '<br>',
  '\r\n' => '<br>',
  '\n\r' => '<br>',
  'badword1' => '********',
  'badword2' => '********'
);

foreach($replaceableText as $replace => $replacedWith) {
    $msg = str_replace($replace, $replacedWith, $msg);
}
return $msg;
}
```

EDIT 2:

I forgot to mention this earlier, but this is for an HTML email script.

This way I can type something simple such as `<h1>` and it automatically gets converted to a header tag with preset inline styles.

Maybe something like this:

```
function replaceText($msg) {
$replaceableText = array(
  'xD'  => '<img src="emoticons/devil.png" height="18" width="18">',
  '>:)' => '<img src="emoticons/devil.png" height="18" width="18">',
  'x('  => '<img src="emoticons/angry.png" height="18" width="18">',
  ':((' => '<img src="emoticons/cry.png" height="18" width="18">',
  ':*'  => '<img src="emoticons/kiss.png" height="18" width="18">',
  ':))' => '<img src="emoticons/laugh.png" height="18" width="18">',
  ':D'  => '<img src="emoticons/laugh.png" height="18" width="18">',
  ':-D' => '<img src="emoticons/laugh.png" height="18" width="18">',
  ':x'  => '<img src="emoticons/love.png" height="18" width="18">',
  '(:|' => '<img src="emoticons/sleepy.png" height="18" width="18">',
  ':)'  => '<img src="emoticons/smile.png" height="18" width="18">',
  ':-)' => '<img src="emoticons/smile.png" height="18" width="18">',
  ':('  => '<img src="emoticons/sad.png" height="18" width="18">',
  ':-(' => '<img src="emoticons/sad.png" height="18" width="18">',
  ';)'  => '<img src="emoticons/wink.png" height="18" width="18">',
  ';-)' => '<img src="emoticons/wink.png" height="18" width="18">',
  '\n' => '<br>',
  '\r' => '<br>',
  '\r\n' => '<br>',
  '\n\r' => '<br>',
  'badword1' => '********',
  'badword2' => '********',
  '<h1>' => '<h1 style="InlineStylesForHTMLEmail">'
);
foreach($replaceableText as $replace => $replacedWith) {
    $msg = str_replace($replace, $replacedWith, $msg);
}
return $msg;
}
```

Comment: `str_replace` takes arrays.

Comment: your user defined function can contain as many php functions as needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[edit] sorry I couldn't help but do it the way I would if it were my project. A repeatable non-redundant process.

```
$array = [
    '<img src="emoticons/{{value}}" height="18" width="18">' => [
        ':)' => 'smile.png', 
        ';)' => 'wink.png' 
    ],
    '<br>' => ['\n', '\r'],
    '****' => ['4lettercussword', '4lettercussword'],
    '*****' => '5lettercussword'
];

function filterText($array, &$msg) {
    foreach($array as $key => $value) {
        if(is_array($value)) {
           if(array_keys($value) !== range(0, count($value) - 1)) {
              foreach($value as $k => $v) {
                  $msg = str_replace($k, str_replace('{{value}}', $v, $key), $msg);
              }
           } else {
               for($i = 0;$i < count($value);$i++) {
                   $msg = str_replace($value[$i], $key, $msg);
               }
           }
        } else {
            $msg = str_replace($value, $key, $msg);
        }
    }
}

$msg = '4lettercussword :) \n';
filterText($array, $msg);
echo $msg;
```

output:

```
**** <img src="emoticons/smile.png" height="18" width="18"> <br>
```

The key in the array is what will replace the value. If the key includes a {{value}} identifier then it knows the array pointed to will be associative, and that it needs to take the value from that array and plug it into the {{value}} identifier in your key. If any key equals a simple array of values it will replace any of those values with the key. This always you to have different html tags and replace only portions of it with a key value str_replace.

Comment: What about the line breaks? Is that possible to incorporate? I'm not sure when you first viewed my question but i added an edit of a code i wrote and I'm curious if it would do the trick properly.

Comment: I added it to edit. Sorry about that. I assumed those would never change or at least would change seldom enough that they could be hardcoded into the function.

Comment: Oh you didn't want to do it that way. Give me a minute. I missed the point there for a second. I'll come up with something.

Comment: I like where yours is going, I tested my edit and it doesn't appear to be working. Any ideas what I may have done wrong in mine? I thought i had it, but beginner mistakes :)

Comment: Sec. I realized the main difference here is the image. Everything else is changed directly by key value, So we want to check for the image instead of the other way around. That way you're array can always be editable. And you don't want to have to write the <img tag into all of the array elements because it's horrible redundant.

Comment: Well I plan on adding more to it than just this really. I'm setting this up for an HTML email script that way if i put in `<h1>` it gets converted to `<h1 style="InlineStylesForEmail">`

Comment: Oh then yeah you just need a straight replace.

Comment: That's one reason I wouldn't mind sticking to what I'm trying to write, but the code isn't working. My mail script is failing, so I don't think i'm returning the replaced text properly.

Comment: I have one more idea. If you're okay with giving me just a few more minutes, with your criteria in mind.

Comment: I'm just trying to find something that works and your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I just got mine working, but the line breaks aren't working.

Comment: Give that function a shot. It may be a little confusing at first but it will allow you to not have to keep changing and rewriting things all of the time. I can answer questions to help you understand how the array works.

Answer (score 1):

`nl2br` will insert HTML line breaks before all newlines in a string.

Here is my code snippet.

```
function replaceText($val)
{
    $search = array(
      'xD',
      '>:)',
      'x(',
      ':((',
      ':*',
      ':))',
      ':D',
      ':-D',
      ':x',
      '(:|',
      ':)',
      ':-)',
      ':(',
      ':-(',
      ';)',
      ';-)',
      'Badword1'
    );

    $replace = array(
      '<img src="emotions/devil.png" height="18" width="18" />',
      '<img src="emotions/devil.png" height="18" width="18" />',
      '<img src="emotions/angry.png" height="18" width="18" />',
      '<img src="emotions/cry.png" height="18" width="18" />',
      '<img src="emotions/kiss.png" height="18" width="18" />',
      '<img src="emotions/laugh.png" height="18" width="18" />',
      '<img src="emotions/laugh.png" height="18" width="18" />',
      '<img src="emotions/laugh.png" height="18" width="18" />',
      '<img src="emotions/love.png" height="18" width="18" />',
      '<img src="emotions/sleepy.png" height="18" width="18" />',
      '<img src="emotions/smile.png" height="18" width="18" />',
      '<img src="emotions/smile.png" height="18" width="18" />',
      '<img src="emotions/sad.png" height="18" width="18" />',
      '<img src="emotions/sad.png" height="18" width="18" />',
      '<img src="emotions/wink.png" height="18" width="18" />',
      '<img src="emotions/wink.png" height="18" width="18" />',
      '********'
    );
    $val = str_replace( $search, $replace, $val );
    $val = nl2br($val);
    return $val;
}

replaceText($textareaText);
```