# PHP Search & Replace Bad Words

Tags: php, html

how or whats the best way to replace the bad words in paragraphs?

i was looking at here: http://deaduseful.com/blog/googles-official-profanity-api/ but not sure how to implement it.

```
function is_profanity($q,$json=0) {
    $q=urlencode(preg_replace('/[\W+]/',' ',$q));
    $p=file_get_contents('http://www.wdyl.com/profanity?q='.$q);
    if ($json) { return $p; }
    $p=json_decode($p);
    return ($p->response=='true')?1:0;
}

paragraph example:
<p>The quick dick, brown fox jumps over a lazy dog. DJs flock by when MTV ax quiz prog. Junk MTV quiz graced by fox whelps. Bawds jog, flick quartz, vex nymphs. Waltz, bad nymph, for quick jigs vex fuck!</p>

expected result:
<p>The quick <span style="text-decoration: line-through;">dick</span>, brown fox jumps over a lazy dog. DJs flock by when MTV ax quiz prog. Junk MTV quiz graced by fox whelps. Bawds jog, flick quartz, vex nymphs. Waltz, bad nymph, for quick jigs vex <span style="text-decoration: line-through;">fuck</span>!</p>
```

Comment: Create an array that stores all bad words, then http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8801486/efficient-way-to-test-string-for-certain-words

Comment: If thepiece of text you are checking is short then the performance hit for testing each word will not be too noticeable - but if the text was several hundred words then it would really hit performance and, depending upon the T&C of the service, would probably put you over your quota. Create your own array and use that as the source of bad words ( https://gist.github.com/1112488 )

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use a package for this kind of task.

I've done a little search and found this one.
--> https://github.com/snipe/banbuilder

Answer (score 0):

You can create `search` array and `replace` array and use `str_replace` function.

In this case your search array would be the json response.

Traverse through your search array and create replace array.

Use `str_replace($search_arr, $replace_arr, $text);`

Here is the link to my answer on similar post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31632175/4139967

You will have to modify it a little as per your requirement.

Comment: how do i wrap the bad word with `<span></span>`

Comment: Do you have array of bad words?